# Merging dummy DataFrames in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of DataFrames that are dummy variables for my dataset. I am trying to find a way to add all these dummy variables into a larger master dummy DataFrame.  Where the complexity starts to come in is that some the tags are the same between the DataFrames.  NOTE: the tags are supposed to be the same names, I need to merge them in a way that involves getting all the data under the current dummy names.  Example data below

```
nested_dummies = [
    DataFrame1,
    DataFrame2,
    DataFrame3,
    ... ,
    DataFrame10
]
```

my issue with this is that some the dummy variables have the same name and have to be merged to keep the "1"

```
DataFrame1
   tag1 tag2  tag3         tag4 .....
0   0    1      0           1
1   0    0      1           1
2   1    1      0           0
3   1    1      0           0
4   0    1      0           0
5   0    0      0           0


DataFrame2
   tag2 tag4   tag5        tag9 .....
0   1    1      0           0
1   0    0      1           1
2   0    0      0           0
3   0    0      0           1
4   0    0      1           1
5   0    1      0           0


DataFrame3
   tag1 tag3   tag4        tag6 .....
0   0    1      0           1
1   0    0      1           1
2   1    1      0           0
3   1    0      0           0
4   0    1      0           0
5   1    0      0           1
```

In total, I have 10 of these DataFrames.  In the end what I need is to have a single Dataframe that has 1 of each of the tags with an appropriate 1 or 0 based on the dummy values in the 10 Dataframes.

I have tried concat, combine_first, a number of different methods I built out by hand, but I could not get anything to 1) not overwrite the previous values & 2) add the values to the existing column

Any ideas?

FTIW: This issue derived from having a ";" separated string as a data point in a column.  I have extracted this information into 10 "tag" columns.  These tag columns are what made the DataFrames

Comment: Yes... I have lot's of ideas.  First thing is first.  And that is I need to understand the problem.  You have not demonstrated what the result should look like and the way you described the 'complexity' was... ***complex***.  E.G. from `df1.tag1` should be combined with `df2.tag2`?  Because you want to ignore the column names?  Or do you want to align according to column names and you consider that they are out of order to be complex?  Also, you want the final result to be zeros and ones.  What happens when there are ones from two different dataframes?  Or! do you mean to stack them?

Comment: The part that is complex is that each DataFrame does not have each column.  I need all tag1's to be compiled together into a single column.  If a dummy is present in one of the DataFrames it needs to be represented in the result DataFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I know what you're looking for -- that if any of the frames has a 1 in an (index, tag) cell, you want a 1 in the final frame, and 0 otherwise -- you could `concat` and then `groupby`:

```
In [31]: pd.concat(dfs).groupby(level=0).any().astype(int)
Out[31]: 
   tag1  tag2  tag3  tag4  tag5  tag6  tag9
0     0     1     1     1     0     1     0
1     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
2     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
3     1     1     0     0     0     0     1
4     0     1     1     0     1     0     1
5     1     0     0     1     0     1     0
```

`.max()` should work as well.

(I may be assuming too much here -- I've done something similar in the past, and so I may have used my own experience to fill in the gaps that piRSq has drawn attention to.)